# c# drawing, circle goes outside form

Tags: c#, drawing, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle within my form.
But it is strange to me I set form width and height to a fixed number, i do the same for the circle, but the circle figure goes outside the form.

```
private void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{        
    this.SuspendLayout();

    gr = this.CreateGraphics();
    gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    Brush fill_circ3 = Brushes.Blue;

    Pen ellipse_pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);            
    ellipse_pen.Width = (float)2.0;

    this.Width = this.Height = 400;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    gr.DrawEllipse(ellipse_pen, rect);

    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

The 3rd and 4th parameters of the Rectangle constructor defines the size in width and height of the circle.

See the circle I got

[image]

Why does the circle goes outside the form???! I have set form and circle sizes the same!!!

Comment: How do you draw the circle?

Comment: `width` and `height` include the size of the title bar and border.

Comment: @FrancescoN  Please improve this question by adding more detail such as sample code to draw Circle.

Comment: I have added the drawEllipse method to draw the circle, thank you guys

Comment: @500-InternalServerError how do I retrieve the width and height of title bar and border? Anyway see the right part of the form, i don't think the left border does occupy so much space, it wll be just 1-2px. The circle part missing on the right part of the form is much more.

Comment: Side note: `using(Pen ellipse_pen = new Pen(Color.Blue)) {...}` do not forget to *release* `HPen` *unmanaged* resource

Comment: Have you considered doing this in WPF? It's got pretty good drawing support, and is very good at scaling things automatically. Plus you can draw objects that are clickable and animatable.

Comment: @RobinBennett now I am interested! I have read sometimes about WPF, but never studied or coded with it. Do you think I can merge WPF in a c# form and with c# language, in a c# application?

Comment: You can definitely use WPF for the GUI and C# for the code, and you can mix WinForms and WPF in the same project but I'm not sure if you could put a WPF control on a WinForms window. There's a lot to learn, but there are lots of benefits too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use the Window size, not the ["client" size](http://The%20client%20area%20of%20a%20control%20is%20the%20bounds%20of%20the%20control,%20minus%20the%20nonclient%20elements%20such%20as%20scroll%20bars,%20borders,%20title%20bars,%20and%20menus.). Just replace your code by this:

```
gr.DrawEllipse(ellipse_pen, this.ClientRectangle);
```

> The client area of a control is the bounds of the control, minus the
>   nonclient elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and
>   menus.

Comment: Hey Man! thank you so much! But what if I would like to draw a circle, starting from an (x,y) Point and with fixed width and height of my choice? I don't think I can use this.ClientRectangle..

Comment: Because I am trying to build a doughnut chart (So double circle needed), but I don't want to use the chart from C# libraries, I need more control over the chart.

Comment: @FrancescoN - oh, you are free to create a rectangle of your choice of course, but use ClientRectangle.Width and Height as a basis for your computations instead of this.Width and Height.